# How to notify all component which has defined listen to specify Event in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx

I define a event  and  I would like to notify all component which has define listener in project .
The following is event code snippet;

```
/**
 * 消息事件
 */
public class ChatEvent extends Event {
    public static final EventType<ChatEvent> CHAT_ANY = new EventType<>(Event.ANY, "CHAT");


    public static final EventType<ChatEvent> RECEIVE_CHAT = new EventType<>(CHAT_ANY, "CHAT_RECEIVE");


    private final Chat.ChatMessage chatMessage ;


    public ChatEvent(  EventType<? extends Event> eventType, Chat.ChatMessage chatMessage ) {
        super(eventType);
        this.chatMessage = chatMessage ;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSource() {
        return chatMessage;
    }


    public Chat.ChatMessage getChatMessage(){
        return chatMessage;
    }


    public ChatEvent(Object source, EventTarget target, EventType<? extends Event> eventType,Chat.ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        super(source, target, eventType);
        this.chatMessage = chatMessage;
    }
}
> Event definition
```

> Conponent eventHandler

```
receiveMessage.addEventHandler(ChatEvent.RECEIVE_CHAT , (chat)-> {
            log.info("client receive message");
            Chat.ChatMessage chatMessage = chat.getChatMessage();
            MessagePane msgPane = new MessagePane(chatMessage);
            vBox.getChildren().add(msgPane);
            receiveMessage.setText(chatMessage.getContent());
        });
```

Above is all about event , and  the I use the below method to fire event .

```
   
        Runnable fireEvent = () -> EventUtil.fireEvent( receiveMessage,chatEvent );
        if (!Platform.isFxApplicationThread()){
            Platform.runLater(fireEvent);
        }
        else {
            fireEvent.run();
        }
```

Above code snippet `EventUtil.fireEvent` just only fire the specify component , it is not desired .

> Major question

Is there some method could notify all component which has define eventHander ?

Comment: There's not an easy way to do this. Only thing I can think of is to get all the leaf nodes of the scene graph, then fire the event at each of them (though that runs the risk of notifying a node multiple times due to how the capturing/bubbling of events work). But a UI event is really the wrong way to do this. You should have a model, and that model should be observable. Then share that model instance with every UI component that needs it. That way the model serves as the single source of truth, and UI code can add listeners as needed.

Comment: @Slaw , Thanks,  I got it . There should be  a context which is single instance and  make sure that  event in context  would be notify  at most or at least once .  Every event node should be register in this context and confirm its visible  that could control event more compact.

Comment: Well, yes... but no. Again, using a UI event for this is conceptually wrong. And by "UI event", I mean an event that inherits from `javafx.event.Event`. You should have a model independent of the UI. Make that model observable. Share the model as needed. Observe the model and update the UI accordingly. I recommend researching architectures like Model-View-Controller (MVC), Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM), and so on.

Comment: okay, Is there some related article for reference?

Comment: I agree that JavaFX events are probably the wrong thing for what you are trying to do.  On the other hand, advising on a “right” alternative is difficult and out of scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: Some things to consider: an [event bus](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained), but even Google who wrote it don’t recommend it and recommend [RXJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) instead (not something I have experience with). May be simpler and sufficient to stick with JavaFX properties, listeners and binding using [mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx). If it is network based messaging subscriptions for chat, that is often implemented with websockets or JMX or Stomp or a custom chat protocol.

Comment: @jewelsea In this project ,  I use reactor-netty as network framework  and protobuf  as transport protocol  . you reminded of me ,It may be better way to solve mine scenario that based on reactive programming (Reactor) framework and  bind the event with reactive model.